# I cannot connect by ipv6 from aws ec2 after all the essential steps (I learned from the internet)

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ipv6, icmp, cidr

After referencing many of the websites teaching me how to use ipv6 from AWS EC2 instances, I find it not working. Why?

From AWS EC2 Console,
it seems that my only instance has its ipv6 address.
And I've opened the ICMP IPV6, together with other necessary ipv6 ports, with source identified both 0.0.0.0/0, ::/0.
I've configured the VPC and subnet associated with that instance so they have ipv6 CIDR, and will automatically dispatch ipv6 addresses.
I've also configured that the router associated with the subnet, to have both 0.0.0.0/0, ::/0 paired with igw-xxx (Internet gateway? I guess)

After all these operations, I still can't find any correct records when in shell, typing
`ip -6 addr` which I believe there should be some v6 address not starting with fe80:, but actually not.

Is there anything else I should do?

Comment: Did you add an egress only internet gateway to the VPC?

Comment: @Maurice Thanks for your comment, but actually I'm new to EC2 and I guess you meant  if there was any problem in my router settings. I had these 4 lines on my router
`172.x.0.0/16 - target local
2406:xx:xx:xx::/56 - target local
0.0.0.0/0 - target igw-xxxxx
::/0 - target igw-xxxxx`
and everything on ipv4 works fine(I simply use the same VPC/subnet/router for additional ipv6 settings)

Answer (score 0):

`Egress Only Internet Gateway(EOIG)` is needed to access `IPv6 websites` from the EC2 instances in `private subnet`.

In addition, `NAT Gateway`(NATG) is needed to access `IPv4 websites` from the EC2 instances in `private subnet`.

- EOIG (Only IPv6 outgoing traffic)
- NATG (Only IPv4 outgoing traffic)

You can find `EOIG` on the left pane which `NAT Gateway` also is. Then, make one `EOIG` then set it to the route table associated with private subnet.

Comment: Thank you for your kindly reply, and i’ll check this after the golden week

Comment: You're welcome. I think "Egress Only Internet Gateway(EOIG)" is needed in your case. Enjoy your golden week!!

Comment: The documentation for EOIG says "If you want your instance to be able to access the internet, but you want to prevent resources on the internet from initiating communication with your instance, you can use an egress-only internet gateway." - ie you can also use an internet gateway if you might want IPv6 in. An EOIG isn't needed, as an IG is also an option.